# SignalR client function cant access to updated $scope variables

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, angularjs-scope, signalr

I have making a web app using AngularJS, .NET 4.5 and SignalR.
One page in the app includes list of tasks to do, and I getting the list of the tasks from the server by AJAX and web method.

After it, I am registering to SignalR Hub witch the work of it is to update the tasks status.

I have angular service for connecting to SignalR and for the function on,off and invoke:

```
.factory('hubProxy', ['$rootScope',
  function ($rootScope) {

      function backendFactory(hubName) {
          var connection = $.hubConnection("http://localhost:52158/");
          var proxy = connection.createHubProxy(hubName);
          proxy.on("dummy", function () { // do not remove - dummy is must here
          });
          connection.start().done(function () { });

          return {
              on: function (eventName, callback) {
                  proxy.on(eventName, function (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j) {
                      $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                          if (callback) {
                              callback(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j);
                          }
                      });
                  });
              },
              off: function (eventName, callback) {
                  proxy.off(eventName, function (result) {
                      $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                          if (callback) {
                              callback(result);
                          }
                      });
                  });
              },
              invoke: function (methodName, arg1, arg2, callback) {
                  proxy.invoke(methodName, arg1, arg2)
                  .done(function (result) {
                      $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                          if (callback) {
                              callback(result);
                          }
                      });
                  });
              }
          };
      };

      return backendFactory;
  }]);
```

After it I am getting the task hub:

```
var tasksHub = hubProxy('taskHub');
```

Then to change task status I am using the following:

```
tasksHub.invoke("changeTaskStatus", task, status);
```

**Until here everything works perfect.**

The server hub function (changeTaskStatus) doing the following:

```
task.ChangeStatus((GeneralVars.PROJECT_STATUS)status);
Clients.All.taskStatusChanged(task.t_id,status);
```

So I am getting the task id and the status and want to change it on client side, I am getting it like this:

```
tasksHub.on("taskStatusChanged", function (t_id, status) {
var task = null;
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.levelTasks.length; i++) {
    if ($scope.levelTasks[i].t_id == t_id) {
        task = $scope.levelTasks[i];
        break;
    }
}
task.status = status;
$scope.$apply();
}
```

My problem is, that the client function in "taskStatusChanged" function, does not know the updated $scope variables. 
The $scope.levelTasks is undefiend there even that I am getting it from server by ajax. And if I am moving the "taskStatusChanged" function to the ajax callback (where $scope.levelTasks is initialize) so the function will know the $scope.levelTasks but will register multiple times (every time I am getting the tasks from server)

Is there a way the client SignalR function will get access to the updated $scope varibles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what I did to solve it is to create a service for the tasks, then in the signalr function I am getting the tasks from the task service